# Perl : Decoding Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I would highly appreciate if somebody could help me understand the following.

```
=~/(?<![\w.])($val)(?![\w.])/gi)
```

This what i picked up but i dont understand this.

Lookaround: `(?=a)` for a lookahead, `?!` for negative lookahead, or `?<=` and `?<!` for lookbehinds (positive and negative, respectively).

Comment: [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre)

Comment: [Explain this regex to me](http://www.nu42.com/2010/09/explain-this-regex-to-me.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. I have another question related to same     =~/(?<![\w.])($val)(?![\w.])/gi).  i am trying to match value of $val in target string. i have noticed a new problem. if $val is xxx. and is to be replaced by YY then the regex is picking every xxx@. where @ means any character and not just "."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex seems to search for `$val` (i.e. string that matches the contents of the variable `$val`) **not** surrounded by word characters or dots.

Putting `$val` into parentheses remembers the corresponding matched part in `$1`.

See [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre) for details.

Note that `=~` is not part of the regex, it's the "binding operator".

Similarly, `gi)` is part of something bigger. `g` means the matching happens *globally*, which has different effects based on the *context* the matching occurs in, and `i` makes the match case insensitive (which could only influence $val here). The whole expression was in parentheses, probably, but we can't see the opening one.

Comment: I have difficulty understanding how are these working    "?<!"       "?!"

Comment: @Tanumoy: The former one is "negative lookbehind", i.e. it means "is not preceded by `[\w.]`, which is a character class composed of word characters and dot. The latter one is similar for "is not followed".

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong. so what i understand is value of $val will not preceded by [0-9a-zA-Z] and a dot. wondering why is the dot there ?

Comment: @Tanumoy: Very hard to guess without context. What does the script do? Does the regex check a filename, version, or something else?

Comment: i got your point grt ! wondering if you could guide me with the regex where i can make the first letter of every word in a statement upper case and rest of the letters as lower case.

Comment: @Tanumoy: It's better to start a new question.

Comment: i am not being allowed to ask another question. the website is asking me to wait for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Read `(?<!PAT)` as "not immediately preceded by text matching `PAT`".

Read `(?!PAT)` as "not immediately followed by text matching `PAT`".

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. I have another question related to same =~/(?<![\w.])($val)(?![\w.])/gi). i am trying to match value of $val in target string. i have noticed a new problem. if $val is xxx.  and is to be replaced by YY then the regex is picking every xxx@. where @ means any character and not just "." And i am sorry but cant remove the "." or any other nonalphanumeric character that comes in $val. requesting for help.

Comment: If `$val` isn't a regex pattern, but text you want to match, you'll need to convert it to a regex pattern. `/(?<![\w.])(\Q$val\E)(?![\w.])/gi`

Comment: Thanks a ton ikegami :)  sorry i know we are not to waste words in this portal. But i seriously wanted to show my appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

I use these sites to help with testing and learning and decoding regex:

https://regex101.com/: This one dissects and explains the expression the best IMO.

http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

define $val then watch the regex engine work with [rxrx](https://metacpan.org/pod/rxrx) - command-line REPL and wrapper for Regexp::Debugger

it shows output like this but in color

```
            Matched
            |
            VVV
/(?<![\w.])(dog)(?![\w.])/


                                            |
                                            V
'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
                                         ^^^

[Visual of regex at 'rxrx' line 0]         [step: 189]
```

It also gives descriptions like this

```
(?<!              #    Match negative lookbehind
  [\w.]           #      Match any of the listed characters
)                 #    The end of negative lookbehind
(                 #    The start of a capturing block ($1)
  dog             #      Match a literal sequence ("dog")
)                 #    The end of $1
(?!               #    Match negative lookahead
  [\w.]           #      Match any of the listed characters
)                 #    The end of negative lookahead
```